# To get filename from path Regex

Tags: c#

```
C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Release\sfref.txt
```

How to split string to get only `sfref.txt`

Comment: Are you using soome code for building this path?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need regex...

```
System.IO.Path.GetFilename(fullpath);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) method:

```
var path = @"C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Release\sfref.txt";
string name = Path.GetFileName(path); // sfref.txt
```

If you really need to do that with regular expressions (what I do not advice to do):

```
string name = Regex.Match(path, @"[^\\]*$").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx).[Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.name.aspx)

```
new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Release\sfref.txt").Name
```